# pytesseract doesn't use user-words

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

Im trying to use a created 'bazaar' config file with this format (I tryed setting T and F):

```
load_system_dawg F 
load_freq_dawg F
user_words_suffix user-words
```

I'm using as Latin.traineddata language and created a Latin.user-words in same directory /tessdata
with some words, like:
Monotributista,
Monotributista (with and without comma)

tesseract without config paramethers game me this, around other words, is a 5 pages text **Nfonotributista,**

So I tried with the user-words, maybe it can correct that, using this code:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd =r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
imagen=Image.open("page-1.png")
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(imagen, lang='Latin', config='bazaar')
```

No errors, but same result, I cannot find much documentation to know what's happening behind, is it using the config? is it trying the OCRed words against the dictionary?
Is there anything wrong on my code?

I appreciate any help
Thank you!

Edit: added some character with bad recognition:
First one detects LIL or LII
[image: Detects LIL or LII]

Seccond detects LI
[image: Detects LI]

Comment: If you're using version 4 with LSTM - `user-words` aren't used there by design. But even in version 3 it may not affect your output to the extend you expect. One thing you can do in v3 is to penalize non-dictionary words using config file.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting crazy trying to make this work with 4 LSTM. I will see if post processing works. Have a lot of errors in enumerations "III title" ends up in LiL title.

Comment: Can you post images that you feed into tesseract? It is possible that they are not as clear as tesseract requires & quality can be improved by using some essential preprocessing steps.

Comment: Added the roman numbers where I have more issues with tesseract, I can post process with fuzzy wuzzy or simil, but with a dictionary it will know that LIL is not a word, or is closer to III thanks!